# Google Spreadsheet Script - get Date as number

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some numeric fields in my sheets that are formatted as Duration (which causes them to be treated as fractions of a day). If I use them in formulas, they are correctly treated as numbers.

I also need to use them in a script that calculates their sum. But in the script, they come up as Date objects. Is there any way to force them to come up as numbers instead? If not, how do I convert a Date into a number correctly? Using `getUTCHours`/`getUTCMinutes`/`getUTCSeconds` almost works, but it truncates hours to 24, and loses precision (even if I use milliseconds, although the loss is smaller). The Date objects seem to have year = 1899, which is especially weird.

Currently I settled on this, but I'm not sure if it is reliable enough (the long number is `getTime` for zero):

```
  if (val instanceof Date) {
    return (val.getTime() + 2209161600000) / 24 / 3600 / 1000;
  }
```

Comment: Knowing what the end format that you want the dates to be in, and what you expect to do with them afterwards would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using function `cell.getDisplayValue()`. It will convert time formatted cell into text, like '13:00', and then you may use

- [text functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)
- or [regular expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

and plus sign to convert this into appropriate numbers:
  
    `var cell = sheet.getRange(myRange);
    var strDisplay = cell.getDisplayValue();
    var numVal = + strDisplay.substring(0, 2);`